# function nested not works in angular js

Tags: angularjs

When I use the following:

```
$scope.test = function () {
        this.batchId = false; 
        this.batchToggle = true; 
    }
```

batch id works and ng-show and mouseover event occurs and works. 
$scope.test function its shows upload.view on every batch id.

But when I use this:

```
$scope.searchFeature = {
    showSearch: false, 
            addBatchButton: true, 
            test:function() {
                // alert(this);     
                this.batchId = false;
                this.batchToggle = true; 
            }
```

`showSearch.test()` does not work. and does not show on batch-id upload/view hover Why?

[See plunker code.](http://plnkr.co/edit/gklQvFUUvx4maIczOUA2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working.. check [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qY44PbMYB03AbjBr6PPy?p=preview)

you need to change the call `ng-mouseover="searchFeature.test()"`

as the function test() is defined inside the searchFeature object, you need to access it using searchFeature.

Its the way javascript works and has nothing to do with angular...

**EDIT**

checkout the [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ylaA08iV760MVS5WzYQn?p=preview), its working.. i have had to make several changes to that... let me know if its working as expected

Comment: Yed HarishR I have used searchFeature.test() but its not working you can see when we use
$scope.test function its shows upload.view on every batch id

but when we use  searchFeature.test() no changes occurs on batchId
see plunker again
 http://plnkr.co/edit/gklQvFUUvx4maIczOUA2

Comment: only little problem Batchid is not hiding when mouseover event occurs
i mean batchId should be hide when upload/ view shows on screen.

Comment: [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/ylaA08iV760MVS5WzYQn?p=preview). can you please accept/upvote the answer

Comment: can you explain why we need ng-hide? in both we placed batch.batchtoogle?

Comment: yes but one is ng-show & another is ng-hide... you requirement was to show either batch id or details... so when one is display another is hidden... so the same variable can be used, for showing one and hiding another

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Hopefully it's the functionality you are after:

```
  <td data-title="'ID'" ng-mouseover="test(batch)" ng-mouseleave="testLeave(batch)">
          <div ng-show="batch.showId">{{batch.id}}</div>
          <div ng-show="batch.toggle">
            <a>Upload</a>  <a ng-href="/batches/{{batch.id}}">View</a> 
          </div>
        </td>

    $scope.test = function (batch) {
        batch.showId = false; 
        batch.toggle = true; 
    }   

    $scope.testLeave = function (batch) { 
        batch.showId = true; 
        batch.toggle = false; 
    }   


$scope.batches = [
        {id: "2014BATCH50", status: "QC in Progress. Illumina: 24/50",  date: "10/24/14", qlty: "check", illumina: "none, raw, modified, modified", FX: "modified", showId: true, toggle: false},
        {id: "2014BATCH49", status: "Pre-Extraction",  date: "10/24/14", qlty: "check", illumina: "none, raw, modified, modified", FX: "modified", showId: true, toggle: false}

    ];
```

I reduced the number of batches just for speed. Assign a **showId** and **toggle** property to each batch and work on them directly. You can fold this into the **$scope.searchFeature** structure too, if you prefer:

```
$scope.searchFeature = { 
        showSearch: false, 
        addBatchButton: true, 
        test:function(batch) {      
            batch.showId = false; 
            batch.toggle = true; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes but i need 
$scope.searchFeature.test() its not working properly like
$scope.test(); works properly